# How to write k8s logs into cnosdb through vector?

Tags: vector, cnosdb

```
sources:
  kubernetes_logs:
    type: kubernetes_logs
    extra_label_selector: "app=cloud"
  transforms:
    json_transform:
      type: remap
      inputs:
        - kubernetes_logs
      source: |-
        del(.kubernetes)
        ._tenant = "cnosdb"
        ._database = "public"
        ._table = "vector_log_test"
        ._user = "root"
        ._password = ""
  sinks:
    cnosdb:
      type: vector
      inputs:
        - json_transform
      address: 10.233.83.6:8906
```

The above is the configuration I used. I deleted the value of kubernetes in the log, because it is a map, and cnosdb does not support writing in map format.
But kubernetes contains a lot of k8s cluster information. So is there any way to configure vector or cnosdb to make the writing successful?